# Why cell labels and arrays are blank in cellForRow function even after fetching datas?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have fetched everything into array of dictionary using fetch function and when I use it in tableview cell for Row it is blank.

Also I cannot use array count as number of Rows function as it is empty. Where have I gone wrong?

Entire class code is given below:

```
var faqs = [[String:String]]()
var questions = NSMutableArray()
var answers = NSMutableArray()

@IBOutlet var faqsTableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    fetchFaqs()
    self.faqsTableView.reloadData()

}

func fetchFaqs(){

    let manager = APIManager()
    manager.parsingGet(url: BaseURL.faqs) { (JSON, Status) in
        if Status {
            let dict = JSON.dictionaryObject
            let data = dict!["data"] as! [[String:Any]]
            self.faqs = data as! [[String : String]]
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.faqsTableView.reloadData()
            }
        }

    }

}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return questions.count
    }

    
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! FaqTableCell

    for one in self.faqs {
        let question = one["question"]
        let answer = one["answer"]
        self.answers.add(answer!)
        self.questions.add(question!)
    }
    cell.txtAnswer.text = self.answers[indexPath.row] as? String //answer label
    cell.txtQuestion.text = self.questions[indexPath.row] as? String //question label
    print(self.answers)
    return cell

}
```

Comment: Can you show your json it will help more to give best answer

Comment: You are populating `self.faqs` but in `numberOfRowsInSection` the number of items in `questions` is returned which is 0. By the way **never** use `NSMutable...` classes in Swift if there is a native equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not prepare question and answers in

> cellForRowAt indexPath

because it calls every time when you reload your tableview. so, you can improve your code like below i have improved.

```
var faqs = [[String:String]]()
var questions = NSMutableArray()
var answers = NSMutableArray()

@IBOutlet var faqsTableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    fetchFaqs()
}

func prepareQuesAns() {
     self.faqs.forEach { (objFaq) in
        let question = objFaq["question"]
        let answer = objFaq["answer"]
        self.answers.add(answer!)
        self.questions.add(question!)
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.faqsTableView.reloadData()
    }
}

func fetchFaqs(){

    let manager = APIManager()
    manager.parsingGet(url: BaseURL.faqs) { (JSON, Status) in
        if Status {
            let dict = JSON.dictionaryObject
            let data = dict!["data"] as! [[String:Any]]
            self.faqs = data as! [[String : String]]
            prepareQuesAns()
        }

    }

}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return questions.count
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! FaqTableCell
    cell.txtAnswer.text = self.answers[indexPath.row] as? String //answer label
    cell.txtQuestion.text = self.questions[indexPath.row] as? String //question label
    print(self.answers)
    return cell

}
```

Hope this solution may help you.

Answer (score 0):

According to the code we see, you set your array of dictionaries in the network request, but you never set your questions, and then you ask for it to reload even if questions are still empty. And then you expect it to populate questions and answers inside the `cellForRow` for every cell.. that `for-loop` except for `question` and `answer` should probably be located in the network response.

```
@IBOutlet var faqsTableView: UITableView!

var faqs = [[String:String]]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    fetchFaqs()
    self.faqsTableView.reloadData()

}

func fetchFaqs(){

    let manager = APIManager()
    manager.parsingGet(url: BaseURL.faqs) { (JSON, Status) in
        if Status {
            let dict = JSON.dictionaryObject
            let data = dict!["data"] as! [[String:Any]]
            self.faqs = data as! [[String : String]]
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.faqsTableView.reloadData()
            }
        }

    }

}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.faqs.count
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! FaqTableCell

    let question = faqs[indexPath.row]["question"]
    let answer = faqs[indexPath.row]["answer"]

    cell.txtAnswer.text = answer ?? ""
    cell.txtQuestion.text = question! ?? ""
    return cell

}
```

Comment: i am not able to print self,faqs dictionary array in viewdidload or cellforrow...why?

Comment: Because in viewdidlow it hasn't been set and you wont reach cellforRow because tyou dont have any row count

Comment: @JaseelCalicut Just  edited to correct the full code for you